# Compare the same table and fetch the satisfied results

Tags: sql

I am trying to achieve the below requirement and need some help.

I created the below query,

```
SELECT * from 
(
select b.extl_acct_nmbr, b.TRAN_DATE, b.tran_time,
case when (a.amount > b.amount) then b.amount
end as amount
,b.ivst_grup, b.grup_prod, b.pensionpymt
from ##pps a
join #pps b 
on a.extl_acct_nmbr = b.extl_acct_nmbr 
where a.pensionpymt <=2 and b.pensionpymt <=2) rslt 
where rstl.amount is not null
```

Output I am getting,

[image: 1]

Requirement is to get
The lowest amount row having same account number. (Completed and getting in the output)
In case both the amounts are same for same account (get the pensionpymt =1) (not sure how to get)
In case only one pensionpymt there add that too in the result set. (not sure how to get)

could you please help, expected output should be like this,

[image: 2]

Comment: tag your dbms as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use window function:

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by extl_acct_nmbr order by amount asc,pensionpymt) rn 
from ##pps a
join #pps b 
on a.extl_acct_nmbr = b.extl_acct_nmbr 
) t
where rn = 1
```